# Control Flow C# (Out of Bounds Exception)

Tags: c#

I'm learning control flow and trying to write code for grab 5 different numbers, store then into an array, sort and print. Im getting exception saying the array is out of bounds, but i can't see why, since im storing 5 objects into a [4] array.

Any tips why im getting this exception?

```
    public static void Three()
    {
        var numbers = new int[4];
        var i = 0;
        while (i <= 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter a number: ");
            var input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (Array.IndexOf(numbers, input) != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("try again");
            }
            else
            {
                numbers[i] = input;
                i++;
            }
        }
        Array.Sort(numbers);
        foreach (var item in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(item));
        }
    }
```

Comment: "5 objects into a [4] array" - you may want to re-read that part of your question... As good practice searching for language + exception name (i.e. https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23%20IndexOutOfRangeException in this case) is good first step *before* asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

> but i can't see why, since im storing 5 objects into a [4] array.

Because a `[4]` array hold 4 objects at the indexes `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`. If you want to hold 5 objects you need a `int[5]` and use indexes 0-4. This is why you usually see `i < 4` and not `i <= 4` like you have.

Comment: Thanks. Got a little confused about 0 index concept and was thinking [4] was right because of it.